# Search a String Array in Java?

Tags: java

How do I search a string array with start with keyword?

for example,

```
String[] str = { "abcd", "abdc", "bcda"};
```

when my search string is `"a"` it must show

```
abcd and abdc
```

when my search string is `"abc"` then it should be `"abcd"`.

Comment: You loop over the array and compare the beginning of each entry with your search string. What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: Is it sorted. And is there any reason you can't use something other than an array, like a TreeList?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String[] strArray = {"abcd", "abdc", "bcda"};
for (String s : strArray)
    if (s.startsWith(searchTerm))
        System.out.println(s);
```

Swap `startsWith` for `contains` you wish to simply look for containment.

Comment: I agree, but just a side note that this is a case sensitive operation.

Comment: good point. Do `s.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase())` to make it insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this method:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29