# how do you search for something specific in an array in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search a String Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834270/search-a-string-array-in-java)
>   [how do you search for something in an array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945112/how-do-you-search-for-something-in-an-array-in-java)

I want to search for a file called filename in my array called drive. How do I do this? I don't know how to search for something specific in an array. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the various API related to `Arrays` ? theres   a method in there called as `binarySearch(array[], key)`

Comment: [At least 3 people have shown you before you posted this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945112/how-do-you-search-for-something-in-an-array-in-java) (And for that matter, you never needed to repost.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (File f: drive) {
    if (f.getName().equals("filename")) {
        // File found
    }
}
```